# about CommonCrypto on iphone SDK.. Can it generate RSA keys and encrypt/decrypt?

Tags: iphone, cryptography

I'm trying to know if I can generate RSA keypair from CommonCrypto on iphone. Is there any good guide or doc on commonCrypto somewhere?
Does anybody can tell me what is possible to do with CommonCrypto?
Does anybody can tell what else I am suppose to use to create RSA keypair and encrypt something on iphone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official [Security Overview documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good starting point to get a picture what's possible with iOS SDK.

Have a look at [CryptoExercise](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html), an Apple iOS example app:

> This sample demonstrates the use of
>   the two main Cryptographic API sets on
>   the iPhone OS SDK. Asymmetric Key
>   Encryption and random nonce generation
>   is handled through the Security
>   framework API set, whereas, Symmetric
>   Key Encryption and Digest generation
>   is handled by the CommonCrypto API
>   set. The CryptoExercise sample brings
>   both of these APIs together through a
>   network service, discoverable via
>   Bonjour, that performs a "dummy"
>   cryptographic protocol between devices
>   found on the same subnet.

Comment: Thanks I saw that. Its look a bit not enought doc for me about crypto. But still a good answer to my question. I wonder if there is anything else anybody know about. thanks.